# How to set drive in C

Tags: c, windows, cross-platform

I wonder if it is possible to switch drivers in C.

For example:

```
/*Example*/
#include <stdio.h>;

int main(){
    SwitchDrive("C:\");
    FILE *c=fopen("example.txt","w");
    fprintf(c,"Example");
    fclose(c);
    SwitchDrive("D:\");
    FILE *d=fopen("d_drive.txt","w");
    fprintf(d,"Example");
    fclose(d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DevSolar Isn't it obvious enough that OP is on Windows?

Comment: @DevSolar I'm currently on windows but I would also love to have an answer that includes crossplatforms or both windows and Linux.

Comment: @Fitz there are no "drives" in Linux. Just one tree.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala oh lol sorry, Im a bit new to linux.

Comment: @iBug: Neither from the title nor the tags. And the day I accept Windows as some kind of "default", something in me will have died.

Comment: In Windows, you'd see the answers below. In Linux you'd just use `chdir(2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`SetCurrentDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/WinBase/nf-winbase-setcurrentdirectory).

Answer (score 0):

For best cross-platform compatibility, you need to use [`chdir`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir).

This function is in the C Standard Posix library, which is widely supported by a variety of OSes.

You still need some `#ifdef` checks to work around a specific problem that Microsoft created by deprecating `chdir`, though. Their [entry for `chdir`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235420.aspx) mentions

> This POSIX function is deprecated. Use the ISO C++ conformant `_chdir` instead.
>   **Important**
>   This API cannot be used in applications that execute in the Windows Runtime. [...]

and redirects you to use [`_chdir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/chdir-wchdir?view=vs-2017) instead.